# Extra dll files packaged by JavaFX installer between jdk 8u144 and 8u172

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, java-native-interface

I am building an installer for a JavaFX 1.8 Windows application.
This application contains a JNI.

When I run the Ant script with the jdk 1.8.0_172, files named *api-ms-win-core-*.dll* and *ucrtbase.dll* are copied to the runtime\bin install directory. Those files are not present when I run the exact same script with jdk 1.8.0_144.

I have tested my program without those files and it works fine. What could be a path to investigate to understand how to get rid of those files?

Also, *msvcp120.dll* is updated to *msvcp140.dll* and *vcruntime140.dll* file appears (and is needed).

Thanks!

Comment: Where are those files copied from?  If they're copied from within the JVM's directory tree, they might be necessary to support different versions of Windows, for example.  Just because you can safely delete them on one system doesn't mean you can safely delete them on another system.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Good point. The files are copied from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_172\bin" but I have no idea what version of Windows would need them.